# Zend Engine API version doesn't match required version from XDebug

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to get XDebug working with VS Code on a OSX 10.12.6.

I have installed XDebug using PECL as the [XDebug website](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) says to do. I can confirm I have it installed by going to localhost and seeing the phpinfo() print out (which confirms i have XDebug v2.6.1 installed. And
I have also tried using the [XDebug Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) which also states "You're already running the latest Xdebug version".

Yet, I still get the error below when i run `php -v` in my Terminal.

`Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220131226.
The Zend Engine API version 320151012 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.`

I suspect this is the reason my VS Code XDebug Plugin ([PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug)) is not working.

When i load VS Code and go to the Debug menu, i see the option for "Listen for XDebug", but when i select that option and press the "Play" (run app) button -- none of my break points are hit.

Comment: Viewing `phpinfo()` in browser will give you the output for the web server PHP version. `php -v` in a terminal gives you the output for the CLI PHP version. They are not the same and can have different modules / configuration. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: More specifically, this message means you're trying to load Xdebug compiled for PHP 5.6 into PHP 7.0

Comment: Since the XDebug wizard does not list any problems, can i assume that my mismatching packages are in the CLI Php version?